# How to install prawn gem in rails 3.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 3.0.0. I tried to install prawn gem. but i don't know how to install. Please help me to install that gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the *prawn_rails* gem. You just include it in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'prawn_rails'
```

and then run `bundle install`. Take a look at the readme section here: https://github.com/Whoops/prawn-rails